# Bash / upstart - launch command under another user, replacing current process

Tags: process, users, su, upstart

I'm starting a process *foobar* as an upstart service which should be run under user `joe`. For this I'm using `su -c`:

```
script
    su -c "foobar" joe
end script
```

However the `su` process is still lying around when *foobar* executes. How can I **replace** the process? Is there an option to `su`, or another (standard) utility?

Comment: Can you not use sudo -u?

Comment: `exec blahdeblah` should replace a shell script process with `blahdeblah`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Do not abuse `su` for dropping user privileges.](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/dont-abuse-su-for-dropping-privileges.html)

It hasn't worked the right way for that for the better part of two decades, and it is in fact a tool for *adding* privileges.  As the hyperlinked article explains in detail, it is not suitable as a dæmon helper tool.  You are witnessing one of the very reasons why.

Upstart has [the `setuid` stanza](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#setuid) for setting the user account that the job process(es) execute(s) as, as the *upstart Cookbook* says.

If you *really* want a chain-loading tool for doing this, the [daemontools family](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/daemontools-family.html) of toolsets has such tools in abundance.

Use [`setuidgid`](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/setuidgid.html), [`setuidgid`](http://untroubled.org/daemontools-encore/setuidgid.8.html), [`s6-setuidgid`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/s6-setuidgid.html), [`chpst`](http://smarden.org/runit/chpst.8.html), [`runuid`](http://b0llix.net/perp/site.cgi?page=runuid.8), or [`setuidgid`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/setuidgid.html) in the `exec` stanza:

```
exec setuidgid joe foobar
```

Comment: I do not need an external tool for this, so the default upstart stanza fits perfectly the bill! Thanks.

Comment: I have confirmed that setuidgid works! thank you